# How does nmap decoy works?

Tags: networking, routes, ip-address, nmap, network-traffic

nmap has a decoy option that can be used to give different ip addresses as source ip.

I was wondering how this works, as what i know packets are routed based on their source and destination ip address so when we send a packet with a different ip as source how does the answer gets back to us ?

Is this option works on a single broadcast domain or can it be used across the internet too?
Any link to a document or website about how this works will be great, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "_i know packets are routed based on their source and destination ip address_" No. Packets are routed only by the destination address.

Comment: You are correct, but the question is that when the response wants to get back to us the source becomes the destination so when we use a fake ip how the respone gets back to us ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for the answer to this question. I thought of leaving what I found with a quick search.

> how does the answer gets back to us ?

We are not interested in getting all the SYN,ACK replies back to us. We only need that one reply that comes back to the attacker's IP to figure out that the port is open. The primary purpose of the decoy is to confuse the IDS on the target site. If there are 10 different clients sending TCP SYN to the server, it wouldn't be easy to find who is the attacker, and who are the innocent clients.

Yes, the responses will be going back to the decoy addresses. That is why the following article says to make sure the decoy addresses are also alive because if they are not, the pattern of handshake will be different for the attacker and the dead decoy addresses, which the victim may be able to figure out and pinpoint the attacker's IP.
https://nmap.org/book/man-bypass-firewalls-ids.html

> Is this option works on a single broadcast domain or can it be used
> across the internet too?

I don't see any reason why it should be from the same subnet. It can be any IP address(es)

Comment: Thanks for you answer i was looking for answer everywhere but could not find. Your answer seems reasonable and correct and i mark it as best answer. by the way if you can give any link to a website or article it will be great.

Comment: The link in the answer helped me find more details closer to the points in the question. But in general, to understand Nmap, the video from NetworkChuck [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4t4kBkMsDbQ) seems to be a good resource for basics, then further the Nmap manual [link](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) provides all the details.